# Postgres SQL state: 54000 when copying data to table

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I am copying a batch of csv files to a table, each one being >8M rows, ~900MB. The first twelves files copy just fine but the next one gives me that error.

The only relevant result from Google is a rather unhelpful line from the official documentation:

```
54000   program_limit_exceeded
```

What is this "program limit" and how do I change it?

Comment: have you checked postgres logs for anything more useful?  It is true, there isn't much documentation on this error..

Comment: are you able to load the problematic file on its own, without loading the others first?

Comment: Ah, for some reason pgAdmin wasn't giving me the full error text. It does seem to be  problem with the file, apparently a missing double quote somewhere is turning half the data into a single value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error again due to yet another large file with a missing quote. Posting my solution here in case it helps anyone, though I assume that there are more general situations that can lead to this error.

In R:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

df<-fread("datafile.csv", sep = "@")
names(df) <- "col1"

df[,count:=stri_count(col1, fixed = '"')]
which(df$count%%2!=0)
```

The idea is finding a symbol that never occurs in your file (`@` in this case) and use that as separator so every row is read as a single column. Then count the number of quotes per row and print all the row numbers that have an odd number of quotes. You can then apply whatever fix is needed.